# Как автоматически запускать все учетные записи пользователей (Windows 10 x64 Pro)

Tags: windows

Автоматически запускается мой аккаунт "Админ"
Как сделать чтобы аккаунты "Брат","Мать","Отец" тоже запускались в фоне при включении компьютер?

Comment: Можно подрбнее - зачем?

Comment: На каждом запустить selenium chromedriver, требуются дефолтные chrome профили

Comment: Эммм... `runas`?

Comment: @donRumata эмм а как с помощью runas запустить другой профиль?

Comment: Ну с помощью runas можно запустить прогу от имени другого пользователя. Тебе это же нужно?

Comment: @donRumata нужно именно пользователя

Comment: Ну вот да. Всё будет запускаться с правами того, кого укажешь.